# How can I add vertical gridlines to Visio Gantt Chart?

Tags: microsoft-visio, gantt

I have a very large Gantt Chart in Visio, with major units months, minor units weeks, and about 200 tasks. This is created by importing from Excel.

I would like to add vertical lines to show the bounds of each week.

By default, the formatting is per this image - with horizontal lines only:

[image]

By comparison, in the test Gantt I created below, the weekend columns automatically have a special format. This suggests to me it may be possible.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Conclusion**

By now, I'm pretty sure I have clicked and right-clicked every menu option and shape in Visio. I don't think it is possible to format the column borders, as there doesn't seem to be a 'column' object to select.

**Workaround**

The next best solution I can think of is to manually add some vertical line shapes.

I created as many as necessary, then aligned the correcting (using align top, and putting the leftmost and rightmost bars in the correct position, then distribute horizontally), and put them behind the task bars (using send to back + bring forward once).

Not an elegant solution, but it gets the job done.